# How can I place a Slider in a StackPanel that increases its size when resizing the Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently setting up an application in C# with WPF and would like to have horizontal StackPanel that contains a few buttons and a slider. The buttons should not change their size when I resize the Window but instead the slider should fill up the space:

[image: StackPanel]

With my current code, the slider has no width. It is very thin. I tried to get the width with a binding of the stackpanel. The reason why I put the Slider into a StackPanel is, that the slider itself does not use the rest of the size next to the buttons. My XAML code is the following:

```
<StackPanel Name="controlPanel"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
     <StackPanel Name="buttonPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Button x:Name="btnTlPl" Content="PL" Height="25" Width="25" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1"/>
           <Button x:Name="btnTlSt" Content="ST" Height="25" Width="25" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1"/>
           <Button x:Name="btnTlFw" Content="FW" Height="25" Width="25" BorderBrush="LightSalmon" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1"/>
           <Button x:Name="btnTlBw" Content="BW" Height="25" Width="25" BorderBrush="LightSalmon" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Name="sliderPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Slider x:Name="sliderTopLeft" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
               Background="AliceBlue" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=sliderPanel}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
               Value="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="19" 
               SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1"
               TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="sliderTopLeft_ValueChanged"/>
     </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: How about a grid with 5 columns with Width = Auto for first 4 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DockPanel` works nicely. Also make sure to remove `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` on your `Slider`.

```
<DockPanel
    Name="controlPanel"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel
        Name="buttonPanel"
        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnTlPl"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Margin="1"
            BorderBrush="Green"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Content="PL" />
        <Button x:Name="btnTlSt"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Margin="1"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Content="ST" />
        <Button x:Name="btnTlFw"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Margin="1"
            BorderBrush="LightSalmon"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Content="FW" />
        <Button x:Name="btnTlBw"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Margin="1"
            BorderBrush="LightSalmon"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Content="BW" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="sliderTopLeft"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        Background="AliceBlue"
        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        LargeChange="1"
        Maximum="19"
        Minimum="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        SmallChange="1"
        TickFrequency="1"
        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        Value="0" />
</DockPanel>
```